# convert local time to utc

Tags: vb.net

I have following function to get utc time. dtuniversal I pass to stroed proc of sql server data type time. it works fine upto values 6 PM eastern ( which is 23 utc) it fails on 7 PM eastern ( which is 24 utc) I get error "Invalid value for this metadata".

```
Private Function GetUTCTime(ByVal time As TimeSpan) As TimeSpan

  Dim dt As New DateTime(time.Ticks)
  dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
  Dim dtUniversal As New TimeSpan(dt.Ticks)
  Return dtUniversal

 End Function
```

Comment: That's not a documented error message.  Copy and paste it *exactly* as displayed.

Comment: That is the message I get. I can not paste image here.
System.ArgumentException {"Invalid value for this metadata."}

Comment: We need a short, but complete sample that reproduces the problem. You will need to include the value that is passed as an argument to the `time` parameter of the `GetUTCTime` function.

Comment: When I changed function following way it's saving all values correctly to the database without error. But while  again showing back local values conversion works fine if time selected 6PM which is 23 UTC but when user selects time 7pm it saves 00 hours UTC to database but converting this UTC to local doesn not work for hour starting 00
 --To convert UTC to Local 
Dim dt As New DateTime(time.Ticks)
  dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
-- Local to UTC 
 Dim dt As New DateTime(time.Ticks)
  dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
  'Dim dtUniversal As New TimeSpan(dt.Ticks)
  Return New TimeSpan(dt.Hour, 0, 0)

Comment: Can you edit your question and include that code you just posted as a comment? Also, include the values that you are passing to the `time` parameter that are causing problems. Saying 7PM is the problem is not good enough because there are an infinite number of 7PM times. You will also need to explain where the error message is generated. Does it come from the database or an an exception message. If it is an exception message then post the entire message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The following test code suggests that the variable time(aTimeSpan) should be looked at.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim ts As New TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks) 'create a test timespan
    'Dim ts As New TimeSpan(0,0,0) 'create a test timespan
    Dim oneHr As New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) 'one hour increments

    For x As Integer = 0 To 24 '25 calls to GetUTCTime
        Debug.WriteLine("     '" & GetUTCTime(ts).ToString)
        ts = ts.Add(oneHr) 'add one hour
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetUTCTime(ByVal aTimeSpan As TimeSpan) As TimeSpan
    'i don't like to use variable names that are keywords
    Dim dt As New DateTime(aTimeSpan.Ticks)
    dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
    Dim dtUniversal As New TimeSpan(dt.Ticks)
    Return dtUniversal

End Function

'debug output
'733980.22:23:08.8112022
'733980.23:23:08.8112022
'733981.00:23:08.8112022
'733981.01:23:08.8112022
'733981.02:23:08.8112022
'733981.03:23:08.8112022
'733981.04:23:08.8112022
'733981.05:23:08.8112022
'733981.06:23:08.8112022
'733981.07:23:08.8112022
'733981.08:23:08.8112022
'733981.09:23:08.8112022
'733981.10:23:08.8112022
'733981.11:23:08.8112022
'733981.12:23:08.8112022
'733981.13:23:08.8112022
'733981.14:23:08.8112022
'733981.15:23:08.8112022
'733981.16:23:08.8112022
'733981.17:23:08.8112022
'733981.18:23:08.8112022
'733981.19:23:08.8112022
'733981.20:23:08.8112022
'733981.21:23:08.8112022
'733981.22:23:08.8112022
```

If you are just changing from local to UTC and back:

```
'a test date in local time
Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Now
'convert local to UTC
Dim u As DateTime = d.ToUniversalTime
'convert UTC to local
Dim nd As DateTime = u.ToLocalTime
```

Either you are making this harder than it is, or I am missing something

```
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("10:00:00") 'this is local central daylight
    Dim u As DateTime = d.ToUniversalTime 'this is universal
    d = u.ToLocalTime 'double check
```

Comment: When I changed function following way it's saving all values correctly to the database without error. But while  again showing back local values conversion works fine if time selected 6PM which is 23 UTC but when user selects time 7pm it saves 00 hours UTC to database but converting this UTC to local doesn not work for hour starting 00
 --To convert UTC to Local 
Dim dt As New DateTime(time.Ticks)
  dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
-- Local to UTC 
 Dim dt As New DateTime(time.Ticks)
  dt = dt.ToUniversalTime()
  'Dim dtUniversal As New TimeSpan(dt.Ticks)
  Return New TimeSpan(dt.Hour, 0, 0)

Comment: Following statement gives me local time 3 AM which shoud have given me 2 AM ( I am in US eastern time zone)

TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.Parse( " 07:00:00" ))

Comment: All I did is ran this TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.Parse( " 07:00:00" ))  which should have returned 2 AM (EST)  instead it returned 3 AM. I did not make any hard.

Comment: If you are off by one hour it could have something to do with DST.  When I do this          Dim db As DateTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(DateTime.UtcNow)  I get the correct local time.